# HTML Table Maximum Cell Border radius

Tags: html, css

So I have an interesting question/problem I'm trying to make a table have completely circle cells to display data in. So I was testing different border radiuses I started with 5px then 15px etc.. But the radius of the table cell doesn't seem to increase any more than 15px.

```
.calendar.rounded td{
border:solid 1px #de6457;
border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

Does anyone know why the radius doesn't get bigger, is it possible to make the table cells completely circle.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that to make an element circular with `border-radius`, the element you are making circular must have an equal height and width. If you have a fixed height/width, just set the css `height` to the same as the `width` or vice versa (if you are using percentages, however, you will need viewport-relative `vh` and `vw` instead of percents). If you don't have a set height/width, you should create some JavaScript that does it for you (getting computed style and then setting the unknown dimension to that value, or something similar)